# Adding wicked_pdf gem causes rspec view spec to fail with NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, wicked-pdf

I've got a weird situation and I'm not sure how to even start debugging it.  Would love any advice or direction that someone can provide.

I've got 64 rspec tests - view, model, controller, feature - and they all pass just fine.  As soon as I simply add `gem 'wicked_pdf'` to the Gemfile, do `bundle install`, and then re-run the tests, all 16 of the view specs fail, but all other tests run fine.  Not only that, the entire app runs fine, local and on Heroku.  So it's only rspec that is having the issue; perhaps something in wicked_pdf is conflicting with rspec...?

I don't think the issue is in my code per se, but I'll add whatever I can think of on the off chance it contains a clue.  One of the 16 now-failing view specs is:

```
describe "properties/show.html.erb" do

   it "displays a field's name and value" do
     assign(:property,
       FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:property, stories: 2))

     render
     expect(rendered).to match(/Stories.*2/m)
   end
   ... rest ommitted
```

One of the error messages is (they are all the same):

```
 1) properties/show.html.erb displays a field's name and value
     Failure/Error: <%= ps_markup_field_or_hide("Year Built", @property.yearbuilt, false,

     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `ps_markup_field_or_hide' for #<#<Class:0x007f2b1123e0e0>:0x0000000968d978>
     # ./app/views/properties/_show_body_post.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_properties__show_body_post_html_erb__2822263843794330255_69911472833980'
     # ./app/views/properties/show.html.erb:19:in `_app_views_properties_show_html_erb__3990796008770089996_79086380'
     # ./spec/views/properties/show.html.erb_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4/lib/spring/commands/rspec.rb:18:in `call'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # NoMethodError:
     #   undefined method `ps_markup_field_or_hide' for #<#<Class:0x007f2b1123e0e0>:0x0000000968d978>
     #   ./app/views/properties/_show_body_post.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_properties__show_body_post_html_erb__2822263843794330255_69911472833980'
```

The view that contains the red-herring "undefined method" contains many calls like this to the `ps_markup_field_or_hide` helper function:

```
<%= ps_markup_field_or_hide("Year Built", @property.yearbuilt, false,
                            @property.yearbuiltflag, "A",
                            " (actual)", " (estimated)") %>
```

That function is defined in app/helpers/views/properties/show_helper.rb:

```
module Views::Properties::ShowHelper
  def ps_markup_field_or_hide(name, value, hide=false, 
                              ext_field=nil, ext_conf_val=nil,
                              ext_true_str=nil, ext_false_str=nil
                              )
    title = "<div class='hanging-indent'> " +
       "<span class='ps-details-titles'> #{name}: </span>"

    conf_str = ""
    if (ext_conf_val != nil)
      conf_str = ext_false_str
      if (ext_field != nil && ext_field.upcase == ext_conf_val.upcase)
          conf_str = ext_true_str
      end
    end

    if (value != nil)
      ("    " + title + value + conf_str + "\n      </div>").html_safe
    else
      ("    " + title + "Not on File\n      </div>").html_safe unless hide
    end
  end
end #module Views::Properties::ShowHelper
```

I started hacking, trying to kludge a workaround, so I blindly (I'm a ruby beginner) added an `include Views::Properties::ShowHelper` statement to the controller; then I tried hard-coding the fully qualified path to the method in the view: `Views::Properties::ShowHelper.ps_markup_field_or_hide`.  I even assigned the ps_markup_field_or_hide() method to a view variable in the controller and tried to call the function from within the view that way.  Nothing worked - same error each time - and my attempts were getting so kludgey that even I became disgusted and backed away.

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '5.0.0.1'
gem 'responders',   '2.3.0'
gem 'puma',         '3.4.0'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.4.1'
gem 'redcarpet',    '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'normalize-scss', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.3'
gem 'activemodel-serializers-xml'
gem 'draper', github: 'drapergem/draper'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'fuzzy-string-match'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.0', platform: :mri
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.5'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.5.0'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '1.3.0'
end

group :development, :test, :production do
  gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.5'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.1.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
end

group :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '0.1.1'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.9'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
#  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I'm developing using the Cloud9 IDE.

What else might be helpful... here's the config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb:

```
# WickedPDF Global Configuration
# https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/master/README.md
if Rails.env.production?
  wkhtmltopdf_path = "#{Rails.root}/bin/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.3.1/bin/wkhtmltopdf"
  WickedPdf.config = { exe_path: wkhtmltopdf_path, wkhtmltopdf: wkhtmltopdf_path }
else
  WickedPdf.config = {
  }
end
```

I was looking at https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1644, where adding the `rails-controller-testing` gem caused rspec to fail with a NoMethodError, but I couldn't see how to apply any of the suggestions on that post to this situation.  I tried modifying the Gemfile adding the "require: false" (`gem 'wicked_pdf', require: false`), re-running `bundle install`, and placing the `require 'wicked_pdf'` in several other places, but that only caused other errors and I felt like I was poking around in the dark and not in the right direction.

All in all, I'm stumped as to how to proceed, and if anyone has any ideas, or could suggest the next debugging step, I'd truly appreciate it.

Thank you so much -- Derek.

PS. I run my tests on cloud9 using: `xvfb-run bundle exec spring rspec spec --format doc`, and I am using an external mysql database.  I also have the ability to run my tests locally on sqlite, which I usually do for speed because the external service is so slow, but I've tried the tests both using mysql and sqlite and I get the same error messages either way.

PPS. My current workaround is I comment out the wicked_pdf gem and the wicked_pdf.rb file, re-run bundle install and run all the tests, then when I get around to writing the PDF specs, I'll "turn back on" the wicked_pdf stuff and just run the PDF specs separately.  But that's such a mess, and I'd like to have the tests all running clean in one fell swoop so I can get a CI workflow going (on the todo list).

`$ bundle show rails
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rails-5.0.0.1`
`$ bundle show wicked_pdf
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/wicked_pdf-1.1.0`
`$ bundle show rspec-rails
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.5.2`

Comment: Wow thats the most convoluted code I have ever seen. If you have more than three positional arguments to a method thats way to many - use keyword arguments instead for optional parameters. Its also doing way to much - if your method is named `do_something_or_do_something` else that is a serious code smell.

Comment: Thanks for the code smell pointer max.  As soon as I get this thing working I'll refactor that out.